# Vuze effectiveness of read-ahead option when seeding

Tags: windows-7, vuze

I am running Vuze 5.6.0.0, on Windows 7 64-bit, with 96MB disk cache. There is an option, *Files → Performance Options → Perform read-aheads to reduce disk reads when uploading*. This option appears to be enabled by default.

When enabled, and seeding only (3 upload slots max, 30kB/sec upload limit), I tend to see cache profiles like this (this particular torrent has an 8MB piece size):

[image]

That is, only ~18% hits, with 2.29GB disk reads to serve under ~600MB of data. The average disk read rate is far higher than the upload rate.

With read-ahead disabled, I see about 1/5th of the amount of data and read counts read from disk, with a constant disk read rate equal to the upload rate (as expected).

Logically, this makes sense to me: How could read-ahead be effective when clients are requesting essentially random pieces?

However, on the other hand, read-aheads are enabled by default, and I don't like to question default options. I generally assume there is a good reason it is enabled by default, even if I don't know what the reason is.

So my questions are:

1. Is the read-ahead option in Vuze actually effective at reducing disk reads even though it seems to have the opposite effect? Am I misinterpreting the results?
2. If not, why is it presumably selected by default?
3. Also if not, in what situations *could* it be effective (even if it isn't doing anything for my situation, perhaps there are other uses)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read-ahead is disabled by default - you must have enabled it at some time in the past, or check your plugins.

This option means that when reading data for upload, Vuze reads sequentially ahead the data following the uploaded data it just read, in preparation for the next sequential request from the connection. In your case, sequential requests apparently never arrive, so that the effect of this option is only to trash the disk.

Read-ahead can be disabled with no ill-effects.
In the case that the data is read sequentially, Windows will optimize the
read-ahead much better than Vuze.